# What kind of graph is this, and how can I *minimize* it?

Tags: graph-theory

I have an information structure that I think is a directed acyclic graph.

**Graph:**

[image]

What I wanted to do was to find the *simplified* version of it. Any nodes under another node that have the same inputs and outputs should be merged. So it would look like this:

**Simplified graph:**

[image]

Because nodes B and C have indistinguishable features, they are merged into one.

Does this problem have a name in graph theory? It looks so generic that there might already be an algorithm for solving it.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you then need to go a step further and say that $E$ and $F$ are now indistinguishable?

Comment: No, for the purpose I need this for I would not benefit from merging nodes on the last layer

Comment: I'm not sure, then, that there's a uniquely defined property here that is sufficiently general to have a general solution.  In this case, you're comfortable with merges at layer 2 but not layer 3.  How would you uniquely define the desired result in a more complex case?